# responsive grid: different column widths

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, responsive

was wondering if the following is possible using grid or flexbox.

I got a 3-column layout that I want to make responsive. Now, on the one hand I can use a media query to lets say make all 3 columns full width on <640px screens, but what if I want the first 2 to be 50/50 and the third one full width?
A possible solution could be to use a combination of a media query and :last-child, but I wonder if this can be done without the use of media queries?

[image]

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/ (check the first example)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR0xl.jpg)
[Mobile <641](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NeXH.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body,
    html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bg-color {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }

    .bg-color1 {
        background: #817e7e;
    }

    /*  This is for three box Wrapper  */
    .my-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    /* This is for three box  */
    .my-col {
        flex: 0 0 33.333%;
        width: 33.333%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 641px) {
        .my-col {
            flex: 0 0 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="my-row">
        <div class="my-col bg-color">
            <h1>Col 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="my-col bg-color1">
            <h1>Col 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="my-col bg-color">
            <h1>Col 3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```